# How to automatically expand text inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick, wget

Is there a way to expand the text inside JavaScript when an html page loads without the user clicking on the JavaScript onclick? Is there something similar to add # to a link to force it jump to a section in the page , but forcing the URL to expand a javascript or even all onclick javascript?

For example, in this [page](http://www.citeulike.org/user/dherman/article/791480) there is "Posting history" and "Export records", and without the user explicitly clicking on them the text inside them won't be shown and furthermore won't be saved with html file.

this is part of the code to expand "Export records"

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="bibtex_link"   
 onclick="getBibtex('dherman','','791480'); return false" class="plain">
```

I have a list of URLs and need to get the files using wget, wonder if wget can help or maybe a default setting in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples would be used for the continuation of text within a block element:

http://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

You would use jQuery's:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

For the examples described in the URL you provided.

Comment: I guess these examples if I have the page loaded is a browser , but after using wget to download the page , the javascript text is no more there ! the question is how to expand before saving the file ?